# security cms for S/MIME?

Tags: terminal, command-line, security, smime

Can I use

> security cms

for encrypting and decrypting S/MIME mails? Or is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is certainly possible with that command.

An alternative could be using the openssl-cms program (can be installed from homebrew or similar).